# How to create a view_all_page using Kaminari Pagination

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, pagination, kaminari

I am trying to create a view_all_page using Kaminari.

I have successfully installed the `gem kaminari`and using the `kaminari THEME` in `twitter bootstrap`.

I would like to create a `view_all_page.html.erb` to add to my `app/views/kaminari` theme.

Everything works great so far with my pagination, I just need to add a link/method to view all.

In my `projects_controller.rb`, under `def index`, I have `@projects = Kaminari.paginate_array(@projects).page(params[:page]).per(10)`

In my `index.html.erb` page I have `<%= paginate @projects %>`

In my `app/views/kaminari` folder I have `_first_page, _gap, _last_page, _next_page, _page, _paginator, and _prev_page (.html.erb files)`

I am looking to possibly customize the pagination helpers or figure out some logic to view all in my `projects_controller.rb`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set the params[:pagesize] to the count of all projects.  Your view and controller might look something like this:

**index.html.erb**

```
<%=link_to "Show All", projects_path(:show_all => true) %>
```

**projects_controller.rb**

```
def index
  params[:pagesize] = params[:show_all] ? Projects.count : 10
  @projects = Kaminari
    .paginate_array(@projects)
    .page(params[:page])
    .per(params[:pagesize])
end
```